# Passing objects to methods

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I always thought I understood how this works...but lately I have started really using interfaces and now things arent doing what I am expecting.

using entity framework, I have a service for each object that is responsible for interacting with the database and such....on my one service I am passing the collection of objects to my service as an icollection(of contactinfo) before I pass the object, the changetraker has the right states. however in my method, this is not the case and all states are set to unmodified.

```
Private Sub SaveExecute(ByVal param As Object)
            Dim srv As Services.ContactInfoService = GetService(Of Services.IContactInfoService)()

            If srv.SaveChanges(Me.ContactInfoCollection) Then
                GetEvent(Of Events.EditCompletedEvent(Of ICollection(Of Model.ContactInfo))).Publish(Me.ContactInfoCollection)
            End If


        End Sub



Public Function SaveChanges(ByVal con As ICollection(Of ContactInfo)) As Boolean Implements IContactInfoService.SaveChanges

            Using _context As New referee2Entities

                For i As Integer = 0 To con.Count - 1
                    _context.ContactInfoes.Attach(con(i))
                Next
                _context.DetectChanges()
                If _context.SaveChanges() > 0 Then
                    Return True
                    EnableNavigation()
                End If
                Return False
            End Using
            '  Return Save()

        End Function
```

As I said above the Me.contacInfoCollection has the right changetracking states. But Once its passed to the srv.savechanges it reverts to unmodified. I am sure its something silly I am missing...the whole EF thing can be confusing to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually that is not possible given the way I am using services for my data operations.

this is the way I have gotten it to work:

```
Public Function Update(ByVal con As ObservableCollection(Of ContactInfo)) As Boolean Implements IContactInfoService.Update


            Using _context As New referee2Entities
                Dim entry As ObjectStateEntry
                For Each c As ContactInfo In con
                    If c.ID = 0 Then
                        _context.ContactInfoes.AddObject(c)
                    Else
                        _context.ContactInfoes.Attach(c)
                        entry = _context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(c)
                        entry.ChangeState(EntityState.Modified)
                        entry.ApplyCurrentValues(c)
                    End If
                Next
                Return Save(_context)

            End Using


        End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach *before* you modify.